# Create repeated pole/zero in transfer function---Octave

Tags: signal, control, matlab, system

Say I have such a transfer function with a repeated zero

$$ \frac{s^2}{s+2} $$

How do I enter this in Octave as a transfer function? Perhaps this question applies to Matlab as well. If the zero was **not repeated**, I would have typed

```
numerator=[1 0]
denominator=[1 2]
sys=tf(numerator,denominator)
```

to form the system as a transfer function.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `tf([1, 0, 0], [1, 2])` to make \$\frac{s^2}{s+2}\$? That one has a repeated zero at s=0.

Comment: @Sven B Thank you. The answer is so obvious and straightforward. I wonder why I was thinking that the repeated entity would need some special syntax! If you want to you can write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the transfer function

$$H(s) = \frac{s^2}{s+2}$$

Using the Matlab command

`H = tf([1, 0, 0], [1, 2])`

If you ever want to find the polynomial coefficients of a multiplication, for example to find the expanded form of a repeated non-zero root, you can use the function

`expanded = conv([1, 1], [1, 1])`

Which will compute

$$(s+1)\cdot (s+1) = (s+1)^2 = s^2 + 2s + 1$$

Hence it will return

`[1, 2, 1]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: If in the numerator we have a term like \$(s+1)^2 \, \times\, s \$, then we cannot express the numerator term directly as in num=[something inside]. We must expand \$(s+1)^2 \, \times\, s \$ as a polynomial (the **conv** can be used but in two steps) and then can we use num=[coeffs of expanded polynomial] so that we can use the command **tf** afterwards. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. It is also possible to multiply transfer functions objects directly as well, but I believe it will be slower. Something along the lines of
`tf1 = tf([1, 1], 1); H = tf1 * tf1 * tf([1, 0], 1)`

Comment: Thank you. Yes using several **tf** will work since we can break the given numerator expression in 3 terms and each term acts as a block in series with one another. Good to know this alternative technique of using several **tf**.